# Infinite scrolling with Meteor

Tags: meteor, scroll, infinite-scroll

I am trying to load 12 items only each time, until the user scroll all the way down and load another 12 elements

For some reason my code doesn't work. When i upload another item, i can see it in the admin panel so it is successfully uploaded but i can't see it in the normal user view. i can only view the first 12 items uploaded and it doesn't load anymore items when i scroll.

Here is my code in the client side

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    var ITEMS_INCREMENT = 12; //this one refers to the number of elements to load
    Session.setDefault('itemsLimit', ITEMS_INCREMENT);
    Deps.autorun(function() {
        Meteor.subscribe('items', Session.get('itemsLimit'));
    });

    Template.list_products.helpers({
        applications: function () {
            var limit = Session.get("itemsLimit");

            //return Products.find({}, { sort: {createdAt: -1},limit: limit }); // render latest first

            return Products.find({}, { sort: {createdAt: 1},limit: limit }); // render first first
        }
    });

    Template.list_products.moreResults = function() {
        // If, once the subscription is ready, we have less rows than we
        // asked for, we've got all the rows in the collection.
        return Products.find({}, { sort: {createdAt: -1},limit: limit });
    }

    // whenever #showMoreResults becomes visible, retrieve more results
    function showMoreVisible() {
        var threshold, target = $("#showMoreResults");
        if (!target.length) return;

        threshold = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - target.height();

        if (target.offset().top < threshold) {
            if (!target.data("visible")) {
                // console.log("target became visible (inside viewable area)");
                target.data("visible", true);
                Session.set("itemsLimit",
                    Session.get("itemsLimit") + ITEMS_INCREMENT);
            }
        } else {
            if (target.data("visible")) {
                // console.log("target became invisible (below viewable arae)");
                target.data("visible", false);
            }
        }
    }

    // The below line is to run the above func every time the user scrolls
    $(window).scroll(showMoreVisible);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here how i solved it:

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
  Session.set("itemsLimit", 9); // to set the limit to 9

  lastScrollTop = 0;

  $(window).scroll(function(event){
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) { // to detect scroll event
      var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

      if(scrollTop > lastScrollTop){ // detect scroll down
        Session.set("itemsLimit", Session.get("itemsLimit") + 9); // when it reaches the end, add another 9 elements
      }

      lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
    }
  });
}
```

It works like a charm now :)

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it like this:

**HTML File**:

```
<template name="yourTemplateName">
   <div id="divId">
      {{#each dataArr}}
         //your view here.
      {{/each}}
   </div>
  {{#if noMoreItem}}
  <span>No more items to show</span>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

**JS File**:

```
var pageNumber = new ReactiveVar(0);
var noMoreItem = new ReactiveVar(false);
var mainContainer = // Your element here example: document.getElementById('divId')
mainContainer.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    if(mainContainer.scrollHeight - mainContainer.scrollTop === mainContainer.clientHeight) {
        getMoreItems();
    }
});
var getMoreItems = function () {
   if(pageNumber.get() < Math.floor(Counts.get('countItems')/12)) {
      pageNumber.set(Number(pageNumber.get())+1);
      Meteor.subscribe('pubName', pageNumber.get(), 12);
  } else {
     noMoreItem.set(true);
  }
}

Template.yourTemplateName.rendered = function () {
   pageNumber.set(0);
   Meteor.subscribe('pubName', pageNumber.get(), 12);
}

Template.yourTemplateName.helpers({
   'dataArr': function () {
      return CollectionName.find();
   },
  'noMoreItem': function () {
      return noMoreItem.get();
   }
})
```

**Publication**:

```
Meteor.publish("pubName", function (pageNumber, pageSize) {
   Counts.publish(this, 'countItems', Meteor.users.find(filter), {
      noReady: true
   });
   return CollectionName.find({}, {
      skip: pageNumber > 0 ? ((pageNumber) * pageSize) : 0,
      limit: pageSize
   })
});
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, i was overseas. I tried to use the Pages before and didn't work for me. I am using Mongo.Collection to store the attribute and i already have data in my collection. Is it possible to implement the infinite scrolling using it?

Comment: Yes, I also used the same and it worked for me. But it didn't worked for the server side processing. For that you can create your custom. If you need the custom one I can help you in doing that.

Comment: i would really appreciate it if you can help me with it please

Comment: Okay. I'll update my answer and let you know. Also anything else that you want to share about your requirement other than the listed above?

Comment: the infinite scrolling functionality only, am currently implementing the other functionalities myself and will post any questions if I came across any other issue that i couldn't understand or solve

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi I have updated my answer. Please have a look. I have provided a generic answer, please use your own Collections and View for this. Let me know for any doubts.

Comment: it didn't work with me, I am reading about the reactive-var package to see if i can solve it :)